# How to use "inserted" keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger in SQL Server and the SQL statements look like

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.INSERTTORNADOUSER 
   ON  Monarch.dbo.GROUPUSER 
   AFTER  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE 
@UserName nvarchar(10),
SELECT @UserName = U.U_NAME FROM USERID U WHERE U.U_ID = inserted.GU_U_ID
```

I get an error for using the **inserted** keyword. Error message is like:

> The multi part identifier **inserted.GU_U_ID** could not be bound.

The table structure I'm using looks like

```
Table : USERID

Columns :
U_ID
U_NAME
U_PASSWORD

Table : GROUPUSER

Columns:
GU_ID
GU_U_ID
```

I read this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/inserted-and-deleted-tables-in-sql/) for reference. Just require some help in knowing what is going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: `inserted` is a special table exists only within trigger. Your query should be `FROM USERID U JOIN INSERTED I ON U.U_ID = I.GU_U_ID` Also `inserted` may contains more than 1 row. So your query `SELECT @UserName = U.U_NAME` will not be able to handle that

Comment: Thanks for the info, for the second part of the comment should I consider looping `Inserted` table to handle the scenario for `SELECT @UserName = U.U_NAME`

Comment: No looping please. What is the objective of the trigger ?

Comment: Objective is to add a new row in another table (USERUPDATELOG) whenever a new record is inserted into GROUPUSER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a variable. You can insert directly into `USERUPDATELOG` with the `JOIN` result of table `INSERTED` and `USERID`

```
INSERT INTO USERUPDATELOG ( . . .)
SELECT . . . 
FROM   INSERTED I 
       INNER JOIN USERID U WHERE U.U_ID = I.GU_U_ID
```